# 1D Candy Crush (How to Delete Consecutive Identical Sequences greater than 3?)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

EDIT: Have updated my solution

Prompt: Write a function to crush candy in one dimensional board. In candy crushing games, groups of like items are removed from the board. In this problem, any sequence of 3 or more like items should be removed and any items adjacent to that sequence should now be considered adjacent to each other.

Input: "aaaabbbc"

Output: "c"

Explanation:

1. Remove 3 'a': "aaaabbbbc" => "bbbbc"
2. Remove 4 'b': "bbbbc" => "c"

Solution thus far:

```
const crush = (s) => {
    let stack = [];
    let res = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        let top = stack[stack.length - 1];
        
        if (stack.length && s[i] !== top[0] && top[1] >= 3) { 
            stack.pop();
            top = stack[stack.length - 1]; 
        } 
        
        if (stack.length && s[i] === top[0]) { 
            top[1]++;
            if (top[1] >= 3 && (i === s.length - 1)) stack.pop();
        }
        
        else stack.push([s[i], 1]);
    }
    for (let cur of stack) res += cur[0].repeat(cur[1])

    return res;
}
```

Can someone advise what I need to do to delete consecutive letter chunks that are longer than 3?

I've mostly figured this problem out but if I input 'aaaab' into my function it'll return 'ab'....

Comment: Do you open to Python solution? (Any language specific req.)

Comment: You have to re-think your deletion logic. Basically, the issue is that you're greedily removing as soon as the threshold of `3` is hit, which causes issues if you have a streak that isn't a multiple of `3`. Can you think of a way of holding off deletion until all characters of a streak have been checked?

Comment: Actually your algorithm has a far more fundamental problem: try the strings "aaabbba", "aaabbbaaabba", etc..

Comment: Have updated my original comment. Think I've solved it hopefully.... have tested a few different inputs and it seems to work.

Comment: You could post your own solution to Answer your question here.